# Can squashing a merge commit cause issues when merging to main branch?

Tags: git-merge, pull-request, git-commit, squash

1. Created a feature branch from develop.
2. Added few commits and pushed to remote.
3. Merged develop branch into my feature branch to get latest changes and pushed to remote.
4. Added few more commits and pushed to remote.
5. Did rebase and squashed few commits including the merge commit from step 3 and force pushed to remote.
6. Created PR to merge into develop branch.

Will these cause any issues because of the rebase that I did on step 5?

Comment: just the commits should be gone which you squashed

Comment: @Satya Sorry, I am not following. Are you saying it will cause issues or not?

Comment: IMHO no issues should be caused

Comment: When you do a squash, you already do a rebase. Maybe you could carry a "hidden" issue from step 3 on step 5 first rebase.